# MVC POST default binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-post

I have an MVC WebApi app. I'm trying to do something basic - pass a string via JSON in the body. My client submits a small number of key/value parameters, and when the MVC router gets them, it begins to interpret the content of the strings.

An example JSON body is

```
{ "myKey":"red,yellow,brown,orange","foo":"bar" }
```

My MVC controller method is

```
public Dictionary<string, string> PostMyAction([FromBody] str1, [FromBody] str2) { }
```

I would expect `str1 == "red,yellow,brown,orange"` but instead I get `"Can't bind multiple parameters ('str1') to the request's content."`

Why is it parsing the first string as a list of parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your Controller method be an ActionResult?
You do can receive more than one parameter on your actions, but for a clear code, I recomend use one ViewModel that contains properties that will represent your View, and Binded on submit.